# How to test and refactor Rails Application which has already been developed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd, agile

I joined a startup where my boss, so called Technology Head with 3 years experience has written the code and the website is running, She doesnt know testing and things are breaking apart now. 
I have been Following TDD in my life, now I dont know how to test the RAILS APPLICATION where 50k LOC has already been written, waste code has piled up and there is no proper flow of the code at all.

How can I unit test the existing modules?
How can I refactor the maximum code with Test After Development approach for the existing code?
I am going bonkers with the existing code. 
Cant make it again, not sufficient freedom to make it again.
Thanks in advcance

Answer (score 2):

You could write a book on this subject (in fact I belive Mike Gunderloy did - Rails Rescue Handbook - though I can't seem to find a place to get it online now).

The short story is:

- Unfortunately, it doesn't make business sense to retrospectively write tests for everything in the existing code base if it's basically working, so don't do that.
- Start always writing tests for new features, and insisting others do too.
- Whenever something in the existing codebase breaks, be sure to write a regression test.
- When you make significant changes in the existing codebase, if it makes sense, add tests at the same time. Don't bother adding tests for small changes that can be easily manually verified; it likely isn't worth the time.

You probably already knew all that though. Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate your revert. 
There are approximately 50+ mission-critical functionalities. 
Problem is, being a single developer/tester I have no idea where to start and how to test the existing models as I have no idea about how they have been implemented or the code flow from one end to another.
How should I start? 
Rspec ?  factory_girl_rails? or Cucumber tests?

Comment: In that case it might not be a bad idea to start with a few top-level full stack integration tests with Capybara. Write some tests that test the happy path, navigating through some of the most commonly used features of the app, and just asserting that the page contains basically what you expect rather than an error / exception.

As for getting test data for those tests, that's a really hard one to answer without being in your position.

Comment: thanks pal! Appreciate!